# Error with my code Unhandled Rejection: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined (anonymous function)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, antd

Having an issue running this code. The goal is I'm working with my react.js program to give a default table if there an error with my Spring boot program. in my Spring boot code, I added a throw exception instead of a return value so my react code is supposed to go to default setting of a blank table.

I'm getting this error localhost:3000

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'error' of
> undefined (anonymous function) C:/demoSpring/src/js/src/App.js:48

```
  45 |   
  46 | })).catch(error => {
  47 |   console.log(error.error);
> 48 |   const description = error.error.error;
     | ^  49 |   errorNotification(error.error.message,description);
  50 |   this.setState({
  51 |     isFetching:false
```

Here the total code below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Container from './Container';
import Footer from './Footer';
import './App.css';
import {getAllStudents} from './client';
import AddStudentForm from './forms/AddStudentForm';
**import { errorNotification } from './Notification';**
import{Table, Avatar,Spin,Modal, Empty} from 'antd';
import { LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const getIndicatorIcon = () => <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;

class App extends Component{

  state = {
    students:[],
    isFetching: false,
    isAddStudentModalVisisble: false
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchStudents();
  }
  openAddStudentModal = () => this.setState({
    isAddStudentModalVisisble: true
  });
  closeAddStudentModal = () => this.setState({
    isAddStudentModalVisisble: false
  });
  fetchStudents = () =>{

    this.setState({
      isFetching:true
    });

    getAllStudents()
    .then(res => res.json()
    .then(students =>
      {
        console.log(students);
        this.setState({
          students,
          isFetching: false
        });
        
      })).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.error);
        const description = error.error.error;
        errorNotification(error.error.message,description);
        this.setState({
          isFetching:false
        });
      });
  }
  render(){


    const {students,isFetching,isAddStudentModalVisisble} = this.state;

    const commonElements = () => (
      <div>
        <Modal
      title='Add new student'
      visible={isAddStudentModalVisisble}
      onOk={this.closeAddStudentModal}
      onCancel={this.closeAddStudentModal}
      width={1000}>
        
        <AddStudentForm 
          onSuccess={()=>{
            this.closeAddStudentModal();
            this.fetchStudents();
          }}
        />
    </Modal>
    <Footer 
    numberOfStudents={students.length}
    handleAddStudentClickEvent ={this.openAddStudentModal}/>


      </div>
    )
    if (isFetching) {
      return(
        <Container>
          <Spin indicator={getIndicatorIcon()}/>
        </Container>
      );
    }

    if (students && students.length) {

      const columns = [
        {
          title:'',
          key: 'avatar',
          render: (text,student)=>(
            <Avatar size='large'>
              {`${student.firstName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${student.lastName.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}`}

            </Avatar>
          )

        },
        {
          title:'Student Id',
          dataIndex: 'studentId',
          key: 'studentId'
        },
        {
          title:'First Name',
          dataIndex: 'firstName',
          key: 'firstName'
        },
        {
          title:'Last Name',
          dataIndex: 'lastName',
          key: 'lastName'
        },
        {
          title:'Email',
          dataIndex: 'email',
          key: 'email'
        },
        {
          title:'Gender',
          dataIndex: 'gender',
          key: 'gender'
        }
      ];
      return(
        <Container>
      <Table 
      style={{marginBottom: '100px'}}
      dataSource={students} 
      columns={columns} 
      pagination={false}
      rowKey='studentId'/>
      {commonElements()}
      </Container>
      );
    }
    
    return (
    <Container>
    <Empty description={
      <h1>No Students</h1>
    }/>
    {commonElements()}
    </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The issue is that if react.js code cant access my Spring program it would go to default code

```
return (
    <Container>
    <Empty description={
      <h1>No Students</h1>
    }/>
    {commonElements()}
    </Container>
    );
```

where `commonElements()` is this code:

```
 const commonElements = () => (
      <div>
        <Modal
      title='Add new student'
      visible={isAddStudentModalVisisble}
      onOk={this.closeAddStudentModal}
      onCancel={this.closeAddStudentModal}
      width={1000}>
        
        <AddStudentForm 
          onSuccess={()=>{
            this.closeAddStudentModal();
            this.fetchStudents();
          }}
        />
    </Modal>
    <Footer 
    numberOfStudents={students.length}
    handleAddStudentClickEvent ={this.openAddStudentModal}/>


      </div>
    )
```

Comment: Check this documentation for clarification: [1]: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: What is the *actual* error response shape? Examine the network tab of your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

in the catch statement try to destructure the error object like this:

```
.catch(error => {
    let err = {error}
    console.log(err.error);
    //do whatever you want with the err object
});
```